# Django automatically enter data in table 2 when entering data in a table 1

Tags: python, django

I have a django model as follows:

```
class M1(models.Model):
    m1code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    m1title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    m1description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.m1title

class M2(models.Model):
    m1 = models.ForeignKey(M1)
    m2code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    m2title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    m21description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.m2title
```

Here i have 2 models with one model M2 has a foreign key to M1. Whenever i make an entry into M1 from the shell, I want django to automatically enter the values even into M2 with the foreign key m1 in M2 automatically pointing to the entry in M1. How will i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by [overriding the predefined model method `save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods):

```
class M1(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(M1, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.

        m2 = M2(m1=self, m2code=self.m1code, m2title=self.m1title, m2description=self.m1description)
        m2.save()
```

Comment: hi it works well. But the foreign key m1=self is not getting populated for some reason. I also tried self.id but in vain. Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: I think it is doing a presave here. But i will be needing a postsave functionality.

Comment: @crozzfire then use a post save signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save